# Why use Observable instead of just HttpClient in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to Angular and I seen a example that fill an object with http, like this:

```
this.posts = this.http.get(root + '/posts?userId=' + id)
```

After that, the tutorial changes this to a RxJs Observable and get the same result. My question is: why not just do a http.get, why they change this to an Observable (and then even more subscribe to that)?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't answer why someone suggested something without any context.

Comment: http.get(...) *is* an observable.

Comment: What do you mean `changes this to an Observable`? How do they do this?

Comment: Oh, now I see... http get IS an observable. Thak you @estus

Comment: You guys should turn these comments into a proper answer. Otherwise this question would be hanging around without an answer forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http.get  is just a Observable, this is why the RxJshttp.get is typed as Observable.